# Prevent Bootstrap dropdown from collapsing until button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Please comment with with clarifying questions. I suspect this question is poorly worded, but it's complicated so it is a tough question to ask.

I currently have a dropup on bootstrap navbar that I've converted to a toolbar. I've moved 2 bootstrap [datepickers](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) into the dropup in order to select a range.

[image]

The problem is that once I select the date for one of the datepicker inputs, the dropup closes. I'd like it to stay open until the OK button is clicked or I click out of the dropup.

If you don't have them, here are the [BOOTSTRAP DOCS](http://getbootstrap.com/)
The line that closes the drop down is on line 798 of bootstrap.js in the clearMenus() fuction:

```
$parent.removeClass('open').trigger('hidden.bs.dropdown', relatedTarget)
```

I've been learning Javascript, but this problem is over my head.

Front-end

```
...
<div class="dropup mobilewidth mobilebottom">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle mobilewidth" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Date Range
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu datepicWidth" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <div class="dpInputs">
      <div class="input-group" style="padding-bottom: 4px;">
        <span class="input-group-addon datepic1stChld">From:</span>
        <input class="datepicker dp1 datepic2ndChld" readonly="true" name="startDate">
      </div>        
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon datepic1stChld">To: </span>
        <input class="datepicker dp2 datepic2ndChld" readonly="true" name="endDate">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dpSubmit">
      <button type="submit" id="dpSubmitBtn">OK</button>
    </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

My css

```
.navbar {
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.dropup{
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    min-width: 30px;
}
.navbar-default2 {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navbar-default2 .navbar-brand {
  color: #777;
}
.navbar-default2 .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default2 .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.navbar-default2 .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #ddd;
}
.navbar-default2 .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #888;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-footer {
    float: left;
  }
}
.container > .navbar-footer,
.container-fluid > .navbar-footer,
.container > .navbar-collapse,
.container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container > .navbar-footer,
  .container-fluid > .navbar-footer,
  .container > .navbar-collapse,
  .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

 .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
  .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-footer {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 25px;
  }

button {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
.onlyMobile {
  display: none;
}
.datepic1stChld{
  width: 63px;
}
.datepic2ndChld{
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.datepicWidth {
  width: 280px;
  left: -165px;
}
.dpInputs{
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.dpSubmit{
  width: 68px;
  float: left;
}
#dpSubmitBtn{
  margin: 0px 2px 2px 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #eee;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .btn-default{
    font-size: 17px;
  }
  .three{
    width: 33.333333333%;
  }
  .mobilewidth{
    width: 100%;
  }
  .onlyMobile{
    display: block;
  }
  .mobilebottom {
    padding-bottom: 8px;
  }
  .WM3MY{
    width: 16.75%;
  }
  .fullwidth{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .input-group{
      width: 100%;
  }
  .datepicWidth {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
  }
  .dpInputs{
     width: 73%
  }
  .dpSubmit{
      width: 26%;
  }
  #dpSubmitBtn{
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 74px;
    border-radius: 1px;
  }
  .datepic1stChld{
    width: 72px;
  }
  .datepic2ndChld{
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .input-group-addon{
     font-size: 18px;
  }

}

.navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-y: visible;
}
```

I don't think you'll need them but here are the [DATEPICKER DOCS](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing some javascript or jquery code(reinventing the wheel). The above scenario can be managed by bootstrap auto-close option.
You can provide either of the values to **auto-close**:

1. always - (Default) automatically closes the dropdown when any of its elements is clicked.
2. outsideClick - closes the dropdown automatically only when the user clicks any element outside the dropdown.
3. disabled - disables the auto close

Take a look at the following plunkr :

http://plnkr.co/edit/gnU8M2fqlE0GscUQtCWa?p=preview

Set

```
uib-dropdown auto-close="disabled"
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you overwrite the "changeDate" event of the datepicker and prevent its default behavior, it should work.

```
$("#myCal").on('changeDate', function(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

You'll need to change the "#myCal" with the proper selector for your calendar though.